# Render html tags in Django send email

Tags: django

I found a tutorial on how to send email with Django. This works as intended. However, when I apply html tags, it is being read as a string. Probably because of render_to_string function, but any ideas how to proceed on this?

This is my view to send email:

```
current_site = get_current_site(request)
mail_message = render_to_string('send/email_template.html', {
     'name' : name,
     'domain':current_site.domain,
})
```

And this is my email template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
<html>
Hi {{ name }},
    <div class="form-control">......</div>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

**EDIT START**
Added my Send Email Function:

```
def SendEmail(mail_subject, mail_message, mail_to):

    context = {}

    try:
        send_mail(mail_subject, mail_message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [mail_to], fail_silently=False)
```

**EDIT END**

As for the result, it is this:

```
<html>
Hi Name,
    <div class="form-control">......</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you telling from your Gmail or something that it is `it is being read as a string`. if it is the case then the problem would be with your html format which is wrong I think. Also include the code for sending email. Because email headers matter.

Comment: rn, I am using mailtrap to test email function. will update the question to add my sending.